# rollup-plugin-esbuild resolve .ts file failed

Tags: typescript, rollup, esbuild

There are a `loading` module in my monorepo workspace, and it has a `loding.ts` file.

So i import it like this:

```
import 'loading/loading'
```

But when i use rollup-plugin-esbuild, rollup can't resolve `loading/loading`, when i change the import to `import 'loading/loading.ts'`, rollup-plugin-esbuild works, but type check failed, because typescript don't allow to import `**.ts`.

When i migrate to @rollup/plugin-typescript, whether load `loading/loading` or `loading/loading.ts` can work.

Here's my rollup config:

```
export default defineConfig({
    input: packages,
    output: {
        dir: 'dist',
        chunkFileNames: 'chunk/[hash].js',
        compact: true
    },
    plugins: [
        litcssPlugin,
        MinifyHTML.default(),
        typescript(),
        resolve(),
        filesize()
    ]
});
```

I want to make `rollup-plugin-esbuild` can import 'loading/loading'